# Junit5 LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder selectPackage does not find tests

Tags: java, junit5

I am trying to write my own Junit5 test runner using LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder, when i use the class selector, I am able to run the test no problem. However, when I try to use the package selector, no test can be discovered.

Here is the code using selectClass that works:

```
LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder requestBuilder = new LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder();
requestBuilder.selectors(selectClass("com.abc.myservice.tests.MyTests"));
LauncherDiscoveryRequest request = requestBuilder.build();
Launcher launcher = LauncherFactory.create();
launcher.execute(request);
```

Here is the code using selectPackage that cannot find any test:

```
LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder requestBuilder = new LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder();
requestBuilder.selectors(selectPackage("com.abc.myservice.tests"));
LauncherDiscoveryRequest request = requestBuilder.build();
Launcher launcher = LauncherFactory.create();
launcher.execute(request);
```

Here is my test code

```
package com.abc.myservice.tests;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import java.util.*;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

public class MyTests {
    @Test
    public void eqTest() {
        assertEquals(2, 2);
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciate!

Comment: Running with JUnit Platform 1.7.2?

Comment: ~/Documents/workspace/email-service-junit - (master) 
$ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.11" 2021-04-20

OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK-11.0.11+9 (build 11.0.11+9)

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK-11.0.11+9 (build 11.0.11+9, mixed mode)

Comment: I wanted to know the version of JUnit you are using, not the version of Java. Can you please add a filter matching like described here: https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#launcher-api-execution

Comment: jupiterVersion = 5.7.1
junit-platform-commons:1.7.1

Comment: @Sormuras i tired the filter as well, requestBuilder.filters(includeClassNamePatterns(".*")); , doesn't help

Comment: Same with 1.7.2? And please provide your complete setup, preferably as a shared project.

Answer (score 0):

This might be because your main folder is not in the same context as your tests.
You can add this to your `build` tag `pom.xml` file so it will compile your test classes to the same path as the rest of the project classes.
`<testOutputDirectory>target/classes</testOutputDirectory>`

Here is an example:

```
 <build>
        <testOutputDirectory>target/classes</testOutputDirectory>
        <plugins>
            ... 
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

You won't be able to select your classes directly with

```java
LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder.request().selectors(selectClass(my.package.tests.MyClass.class))
```

But you should not have any problem with the `selectPackage` method you are using.

There might be other work-arounds that I'm not aware of but this is working for JUnit5 right now.